# javascript Regex to extract all sentences that contain a certain word 2 times

Tags: javascript

For example, I have sentence (str1) which have 2 word *contractor* and (str2) which have 1 *contractor* word. I need a regexp that will extract all sentences that contain 2 word *contractor*

```
var str1 = "Before hiring your chosen contractor, be certain to get a solid estimate in writing because not all contractors are honest and upfront in their quoting of costs."

var str2 = "Before hiring your chosen contractor, be certain to get a solid estimate in writing."
```

Comment: For 1 word contractor I'm using this regexp                                          /[^.?!]*(?:[.?,\s!])contractor(?=[\s.?!,;'s]){2}[^.?!]*[.?!]/gi

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Also do you need to search for sentences or is every string one sentence?

Comment: in 1 string I can have 100 sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined a sentence as anything preceding a `.`, `?` or `!` here. Feel free to adapt to your needs.

To catch one `contractor`:

```
[^.!?]*\bcontractor\b[^.!?]*[.!?]
```

Every match is a sentence with one or more "contractor" in it.

To catch two or more, use this:

```
[^.!?]*\bcontractor\b[^.!?]+\bcontractor\b.*?[.!?]
```

It reads aproximately as: match everything other than sentence ending, followed by the word "contractor", followed by more non-sentence-ending characters, followed by the word "contractor" again, followed by any chars and one sentence-ending-character.

Make sure to set the **global** `g` flag, so that multiple matches per line can be found. You'll also have to trim the outcome since a sentence can begin with a white space in the pattern above.